# How to save a directory only at the first time opening the program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to code a program that saves encrypted passwords in a file, but I want the option to type the directory in during the first use of the program so it knows where to save the passwords. Does anyone know how I could achieve that?

Example, first time opening program:

```
dir = input("What directory would you like to use to save your passwords?")
file_name = dir+"\\passwords.txt"   
open(file_name, "w")   # creates the file
# runs the rest of the program or exits
```

Then, on every run of the program after the first, it just skips this part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to persist the location of the passwords file somewhere, you could try to create a configuration file in the users home directory.

When the app starts, do the following:

```
from os.path import expanduser, join, exists
home = expanduser("~")

if not exists(join(home, '.my-config')):
     # ask for password file path
     ...
     # persist path
     with open(join(home, '.my-config', 'w')) as config_file:
           config_file.write(password_file_path)
else:
    # read the password file path from the config
    with open(join(home, '.my-config', 'r')) as config_file:
           password_file_path=config_file.read()

 # continue with code
 ...
```

To make the config file more usable, you can for example create a dictionary with all the data you need and save a json string to the config file, so you can later read that dictionary back into the application.

Comment: Shouldn't there be closing parens for `join()` where you use `with open(join(home, '.my-config', ...`?

Comment: This was hard to understand for me, but it worked after some changes, thanks!